# What is the proper syntax of excluding transient dependencies in gradle, name or module?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have come across two different variations of syntax to exclude a transient dependency in gradle

One uses name and another uses module. Which one is correct?

For eg:

name:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.19'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:sprin  g-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context'
    }
}
```

OR module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.19'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:sprin  g-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-context'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current documentation (7.4.2) shows `module`:

https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

```
implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
    exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
}
```

`name` is probably a legacy naming. Go with what the current documentation has, `module`.